# Traversing folders with U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to read a full parent directory of file using U-SQL regardless of how deep it is in a source directory structure

`@searchLog =
    EXTRACT FileName    string,
          , Path           string
          , UserId          int  
          , Start           DateTime  
          , Region          string  
          , Query           string  
          , Duration        int  
          , Urls            string  
          , ClickedUrls     string
    FROM "wasb://[blobcontainter]@[blobaccount]/samples/{Path}/{FileName}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();`

What I want to achieve is to traverse folders sitting in a blob container and save path to a file along with data inside. Assuming I have file structure like this:

`"/samples/foo/log1.csv"
"/samples/foo/bar/log1.csv"
"/samples/foo/bar/baz/log3.csv"`

I would like to get value of {Path}

`"foo"
"foo/bar"
"foo/bar/baz"`

respectively

Currently I was able to read only one level of folders in a way it's being returned as Path in the result set using:

`FROM "wasb://[blobcontainter]@[blobaccount]/samples/{Path}/{FileName}.csv"`

Putting a wildcard

`FROM "wasb://[blobcontainter]@[blobaccount]/samples/{*}/{FileName}.csv"`

results with reading the top level and first sub-level folders but it doesn't go any deeper than that, additionally it doesn't return the path in the result set.

On top of that Streamsets are not supported in file list so

`FROM "wasb://[blobcontainter]@[blobaccount]/samples/{Topfolder}/{FileName}.csv"
FROM "wasb://[blobcontainter]@[blobaccount]/samples/{Topfolder}/{Subfolder1}/{FileName}.csv"`

is not an option either.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not available, but is part of our long term backlog. Please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback that will help us prioritize the feature.

Comment: Thanks @michael-rys I will do that. Could you tell me what is the best workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Right now you need to basically union all possible nesting levels if you want to use U-SQL. I would suggest to look into using any of the ADL SDKs (e.g. Powershell) to do the file path enumeration. Also please note that Azure Blob Storage is a key/value store. The key may look like a path but it is just a string.